# NestJs crtl + space in VSCode does not show HTTP method from @nest/common

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs

The Ctrl + Space is a shortcut in Visual Studio Code to show the auto-complete list, but it doesn't show complete list anymore.
My Vscode version: 1.80.2
OS: Window
Before:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkuHR.png)
After:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rajyU.png)

I dont know why it does not show complete recommend list anymore when i use nest/cli [nest new]